# xml processing using php (simplexml?)

Tags: php, xml

How to access certain child's values? Let's say we have an XML:

http://www.more2home.dk/pi/Hvilestol_Model_090_m_skammel_l%E6der_5854_70.aspx?xml=1

How to acces e.g. `ImageUrl (<ImageUrl></ImageUrl>)` and extract http://www.more2home.dk/SL/PI/290/9/a132edfb-16e7-47b3-b781-8c0a973cc46b.jpg?c=0_1

Comment: Please do not ignore [Ask Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice). [How to do things with SimpleXml has been answered numerous times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simplexml+[php]) and there is also [SimpleXml examples in the PHP Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php). Also, if you want us to answer your question, dont make us leave the site.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
$s = simplexml_load_file('http://www.more2home.dk/pi/Hvilestol_Model_090_m_skammel_l%E6der_5854_70.aspx?xml=1');
echo $s->xml->export->exportdata->Product->ImageUrl;
```

or very simple with [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$result = $s->xpath('//Product/ImageUrl');
if ($result) {
    foreach($result as $node) {
       echo $node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.more2home.dk/pi/Hvilestol_Model_090_m_skammel_l%E6der_5854_70.aspx?xml=1', 0, true);

echo (string) $sxml->export->exportdata->Product->ImageUrl;
```